Spring JPA select null as field object instead of tuple with null values
I have two Spring JPA entities and I want to write a left join on some set of their fields. Let's suppose I have
class Foo {
   Long id; // PK 
   Long barId; // FK to Bar
   Long field;
}

class Bar {
   Long id; // PK
   Long field;
}

There are also 2 Java records that I have
record ThinBar(Long barId);
record FooWithBar(Long fooId, Long fooField, ThinBar bar);

Now, if I am writing this code in a JpaRepository<Foo, Long>
@Query("select new com.example.FooWithBar(foo.id, foo.field, new com.example.ThinBar(bar.id)) from Foo foo left join Bar bar on foo.barId = bar.id")
FooWithBar get(Long fooId);

in case the matching bar does not exist, the result would be FooWithBar(id, field, ThinBar(null)). However, what I want to achieve is FooWithBar(id, field, null). Is that doable in a Spring JpaRepository query?

The simplest solution would have been to use a CASE WHEN THEN statement, but unfortunately JPQL does not allow for anything besides scalars as values there, and the new operator is not a scalar.
What is possible, on the other hand, is to override the constructor of the record and manipulate the nullable field to achieve the stated purpose. Thus, this is possible
record FooWithBar(Long fooId, Long fooField, ThinBar bar) {
    public FooWithBar(Long fooId, Long fooField, ThinBar bar) {
        this.fooId = fooId;
        this.fooField = fooField;
        if (bar.barId != null) {
            this.bar = bar;
        } else {
            this.bar = null;
        }
    }
}

